# Get information from a WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

I'm having this problem and I have not found a solution.
I have seen several methods, but none adapts to my application because mine is multiple layer.

The architecture is next:

- Presentation Layer
- Business Logic Layer
- Data Access Layer

Only Business Logic Layer can interact with the other two layers and all the examples I've seen were in single layer applications so none works for me :(

I need to send a full row selection information from the Presentation Layer to the Business Logic Layer on a double click event.

```
object item = dataGrid.SelectedItem;
string ID = (dgwLoadItems.SelectedCells[0].Column.GetCellContent(item) as TextBlock).Text;
MessageBox.Show(ID);
```

tried this but this way needs to reference Data Access Layer on the Presentation Layer and I can't do that for IT issues.

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question. Can you provide some more specific details about what you have, why you tried, and how your results differ from what you want?

Comment: You're rigth sorry, tried to correct the post :D Thanks

Comment: I suggest that you look at implementing the MVVM design pattern - binding your datagrid to a collection of objects. That way you can reference the object properties directly. Trying to access data values by querying controls like this is never the best option.